# Не получается изменить содержимое массива

Tags: c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему выполняя такой код:

```
void test(char * line) {
    line[1] = 'a';
}

int main(int carc, char** charv) {
    char * line = (char *) "cba";
    test(line);
    cout << *line << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

программа не выполняется. Выводится сообщение:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: За полезные ответы имеет смысл голосовать (треугольник вверх рядом с ответом). Если ответ при этом Вам подошел, дополнительно можно поставить галочку рядом с ним. Избегайте комментариев вида "спасибо".

Answer (score 2):

Строковый литерал в С++ является немодифицируемым, константным массивом символов. Его нельзя изменить. Попытки изменить строковый литерал (как и любой другой константный объект) ведут к неопределенному поведению.

Вы сами вынуждены были "проламываться" через константность вашего строкового литерала, когда вынужденно применили явный каст к типу `char *`. Уже это должно было вам намекнуть на то, что здесь что-то не так.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано, нельзя менять строковые литералы. Их нельзя менять ни в C++, где они имеют тип константных символьных массивов (например, в C++ строковый литерал `"cba"` имеет тип `const char[4]`), ни в C (в C данный строковый литерал `"cba"` имеет тип `char[4]`), где они имеют тип не константных символьных массивов. Попытка изменить строковый литерал ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Однако если вы указатель на строковый литерал замените массивом, который инициализируется данным строковым литералом, то вы можете изменить элементы этого массива.

Сравните

```
void test(char * line) {
    line[1] = 'a';
}

int main(int carc, char** charv) {
    char line[] = "cba";
    test(line);
    cout << line << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

И я думаю, вы имели в виду следующее предложение

```
cout << line << "\n";
        ^^^^
```

вместо этого

```
cout << *line << "\n";
       ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

К двум предыдущим ответам о том, что литерал константный.

Более того, компилятор имеет право записать его в память, в которую вы не сможете записать, что называется, физически - например, на уровне запрета ОС.

Этим отличается VC++ :) - он не говорит об ошибке, он говорит - пиши-пиши... но эта запись не происходит!

```
void test(char * line) {
    line[1] = 'a';
}

int main() {
    char * line = (char *)"cba";
    test(line);
    cout << line << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код компилируется VC++ 2015 без замечаний, запускается, работает без всяких SIGSEGV. Но на выходе вы получите неизменную строку `cba`! Пренеприятнейшее, замечу, поведение...

Кстати, Open Watcom всё разрешает и мы действительно получаем строку `caa`.

Comment: Да, заметил такое)